# How many avatars of Adi Shakti are mentioned in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, avatars, devi

I know Durga, Kalaratri and Bhadrakali are mentioned in Mahabharata and they are the avatars of Adi Shakti.

But, are others avatars of Adi Shakti mentioned in the Mahabharata?